# in android studio, while debugging the app BluetoothLeGatt i got the following expectation:

Tags: java, android, debugging, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

In Android Studio, while debugging the app BluetoothLeGatt, I got the following exception:

> Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
>                 java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
>                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
>                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
>                     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.startScan(IBluetoothGatt.java:678)
>                     at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.onClientRegistered(BluetoothLeScanner.java:367)
>                     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:56)
>                     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission in your Manifest and in your code if you are targeting Android 23 or higher.

Add that permission to manifest.xml as well as your code.

[This page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) explains all you need to know about permissions in your Android app.